# Not able to install python3 on Redhat 8 offline mode

Tags: redhat, rhel

I created an offline repo for RHEL 8:

- downloaded all needed packages with `dnf download`
- create repodata with `createrepo` command

I'm able to install most of the packages in offline mode but python3 can't be installed
The error I'm receiving is:

```
No available modular metadata for modular package 'python36-3.6.8-2.module+el8.1.0+3334+5cb623d7.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
Error: No available modular metadata for modular package
```

What can I do to fix this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this worked for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567057/download-rpm-and-all-dependencies-on-rhel-centos-8

There are some packages required like: python3-createrepo_c libmodulemd

And Python module: click

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you need Development Tools:

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall ‘Development Tools’
```

See https://developers.redhat.com/rhel8/hw/python

Comment: This can't help. I need somehow to make my offline repo to be aware of modules. I saw something but for Fedora ... for RHEL 8 didn't worked :-(